# ASP.NET Core Angular 7 Http Post - Requires Complex Object?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular-http

I'm trying to do a basic HTTP Post to an ASP.NET Core back end.

Angular:

```
var parms = {
    userRoles: ['User', 'Worker'],
    email: 'email@email.com'
};

this.http.post('/UserRole/SaveUserRoles', parms)
    .subscribe(result => { });
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUserRoles([FromBody]string[] userRoles, string email)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

My parameters are showing null. I can get this working by creating a complex object C# side, but that's not what I want to do. I don't need an object just for 2 parameters.

What's missing here?

Comment: *I don't need an object just for 2 parameters* is a pretty poor reason for not creating a class. For me at least, it's much more readable than using `FromBody`

Comment: AFAIK you can't do what you're trying to do.  It would be `[FromBody] parms` and that object would have the userRoles and email properties.

Comment: `[FromBody]` isn't *selective* - you can't bind to a specific JSON property from the input object like you're trying to do here. `[FromBody]` will just attempt to bind the input against the type being decorated, which fails in your case as there's no match between an object (the input) and an array (the C# type).

Comment: @DavidG i disagree. Now I have another class file cluttering up my project. A class solely to wrap API input in this case doesn’t make sense IMO

Comment: Worrying about class files "cluttering your project" is a very peculiar thing to say IMO. And using classes to wrap API input seems like an eminently sensible thing to do also. But hey ho, each to their own!

Comment: @DavidG when creating a regular c# method I’m rarely creating a class to hold its parameters. I look at this the same way.

Comment: But this isn't a regular C# method. I'm not saying you need to create a class for every controller action, I am saying that your reasoning for not doing it is flawed.

Comment: @DavidG I’m struggling with your benefit for a class in this case. It’s literally just used in this one spot so reuse isn’t one. In my mind it provides no value

Comment: The benefit for a class in this case is simply that *it works* and is how the `[FromBody]` attribute is designed to be used.

Comment: I tried to explain what i meant with my answer. I actually think this is what TS wants, basically consider the individual arguments as such, and just send them as separate parameters (implemented by querystring).

Answer (score 8):

You have to set proper header for your request like,

```
var postData = {
        userRoles: ['User', 'Worker'],
        email: 'email@email.com'
    };

const headers: HttpHeaders = new  HttpHeaders();
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

this.http.post('/UserRole/SaveUserRoles', postData, { headers: headers })
    .subscribe(result => {
});
```

And for your controller side,

> I don't need an object just for 2 parameters.

But this is a good practice to catch all your posted data in the model or c# object.

So here I create a sample class.

```
class PostData
{
    public string[] userRoles { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUserRoles([FromBody]PostData postData)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to *consider your POST* data as individual parameters. You can send them as "params" which will translate into *querystring parameters*.

`params` is a property on the second argument for `get` and third argument for `post` on the `HttpClient`.

```
var body = null;

var parms = {
    userRoles: ['User', 'Worker'],
    email: 'email@email.com'
};

this.http.post('/UserRole/SaveUserRoles', body, {params: parms})
    .subscribe(result => {
    });
```

You'd want to update your API controller to use the `[FromQuery]` attribute on the arguments that you want to bind.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveUserRoles([FromQuery]string email, [FromQuery]string[] userRoles)
{
    return Ok();
}
```